# How to load an image from a buffer with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qimage

Thus type:

```
QBuffer* buffer = new QBuffer(this->Conex);
QImage* image = new QImage ();
image->loadFromData (buffer->buffer());
```

This does not work for me.

Comment: Why, what happens when you try?

Comment: What kind of image data does `buffer` contain?

Comment: Put the data from the buffer into a QByteArray so you can have a look at how it looks like, then it will probably be more clear what needs to be done.

Answer (score 5):

If the buffer contains raw pixel data, you might want to specify the width, height and bpp using this constructor:

```
QImage::QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, Format format )
```

**Edit:**

That's how you would use this constructor:

```
int imageWidth = 800;
int imageHeight = 600;
int bytesPerPixel = 4; // 4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB
int format = QImage::Format_ARGB32; // this is the pixel format - check Qimage::Format enum type for more options
QImage image(yourData, imageWidth, imageHeight, imageWidth * bytesPerPixel, format);
```

Comment: this command line:
QImage:: QImage (uchar * data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, Format format)
Would use is it so?
QImage image = new QImage (buffer, 600, 400, jpg)
the bytesPerLine not they mean well, will the photo occupies kb?
thanks